# What is the file extension of PHP session file?

Tags: php, file, filesystems, file-extension

What is the file extension of the PHP session file that it generates on `session_start()` inside the `tmp` directory? Is this a special kind of file for session data or its normal file?

Comment: See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Comment: What's your definition of "normal" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP session handling is pretty straightforward:

- You can define different handlers to [store](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) and [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) information.
- If the handler in use needs/supports a file system path, [you can configure it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) too.

It can get as complex as you want but the default save handler is `files` what means good old files somewhere below `session.save_path`. Just have a look.

```
var_dump(ini_get('session.save_path'));
```

... tells you the exact location for current script. There, you'll see files with names like `sess_49ghti073p8jogp1lm8frunane` where `sess_` is a fixed prefix and `49ghti073p8jogp1lm8frunane` is the session ID.

[image: Session folder]

You can also open the files with a text editor. It's not necessarily 100% plain text but it's visible enough to grasp the idea:

```
first_request|O:8:"DateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2019-08-15 17:12:11.932785";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:13:"Europe/Madrid";[…]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`session_save_path()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) - they have no extension, they are long string UID named files.